# Getting user's liked pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I've been digging on Stackoverflow for hours now and found no solution:
I want to get pages that a user liked using the page_fan table.
However, that user is not my friend - is it possible? I think it might be because when i go the user's profile I can see all the pages he liked but not using FQL...Any advice?
Tnx.
Shai.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible as long as the user gave your app "user_likes" permission. See very beginning of below page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/

Comment: well yeah, i know that is possible but this is not what i'm looking for. I'll explain better: I'm a page admin and I would like to see what else interests the people that liked my page. so i don't have any app and can't get the user's permissions...

Comment: ah I see. I'm not 100% sure but don't think you can collect such info without permissions, even they like your page.

Answer (score 0):

query:

```
SELECT name, about, description, keywords, pic_cover, pic_large FROM page 
WHERE page_id 
IN (
    SELECT page_id FROM page_fan 
    WHERE uid =me()
)
```

This query will return data for each of the pages a user that is using your app has liked.